# When will API of "Office lens" be available

Tags: ms-office

I think "Office lens" is quiet a useful tool that turns photos into documents. After that, the documents can be used as input for many other applications. So, I think the release of Office Lens's API will motivate quite a large number of wonderful apps.
Looking forward...

Comment: Has it been available yet?

Answer (score 0):

The Office Lens app has been available on the Windows Phone platform for a while now and recently was made available on iOS as well as Android (Beta). http://blogs.office.com/2015/04/02/office-lens-comes-to-iphone-and-android/
Please give it a try.

Since the question specifically talked about creating documents programatically, the Word ObjectModel can be directly used (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff597928.aspx) to achieve the desired result.